# Make individual onClick() methods for children of expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, buttonclick

I have an expandablelistview as shown below. I've made it so that a toast message will pop up when each child is clicked. I need each of the children to start their own activity/fragment, which required individual onClick() methods. Does anybody know how this can be achieved? Thanks. NOTE: I am using SimonVT's slidingmenu library and I'm pretty new to android programming.

MainActivity.java:

```
package press.linx.expandablelistdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListView exv;
MenuDrawer mDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this);
    mDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawer.setMenuView(R.layout.leftmenu);

    exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

    exv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String itemclicked = MyAdapter.childList[groupPosition][childPosition];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you clicked " + itemclicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

    });
}

private void setListAdapter(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
package press.linx.expandablelistdemo;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
Typeface typeface;
String []parentList = {"Tech", "Best Of", "Art & Design", "Other"};

static String [][] childList = {
        {
            "All Tech", "Reviews", "Gaming", "Gadgets"
        },
        {
            "Android"
        },
        {
            "Architecture"
        },
        {
            "Infographics"
        }
};
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/robotochild.ttf"); 
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    tv.setPadding(30, 10, 0, 10);
    tv.setTextSize(15);
    //tv.setTypeface(typeface); 
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    return tv;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childList[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return parentList.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/roboto.ttf"); 
    tv.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
    tv.setPadding(50, 10, 0, 10);
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setTypeface(typeface); 
    return tv;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

}
```

menulistview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/geowall">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="3dp" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

[image: HERE]!

Answer (score 0):

If you want differing functionalities per button, consider storing them as the buttons' `tag` property (in the XML layout). The `View v` parameter in your `onChildClick` listener is the `View` of the child being clicked; it can then be used to retrieve the tag, like so:

`v.getTag();`

You could either have a switch-case block to call the correct activity based on the tag, or store the **exact** name of the activity in the tag and pass that in via reflection to retrieve the class for the activity. Alternatively, you could store a `HashMap` mapping the tag-names to `Activity` classes/variables.

Answer (score 0):

This might be you are looking for.

Let’s get start by creating a project in Eclipse IDE.

1. Create a new project by going to File ⇒ New Android Project. Fill all the details and name your activity as AndroidListViewActivity.
2. Once the project is created open your main activity java file (in this case AndroidListViewActivity.java) and extend the class from ListActivity.

public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
3. Now we need a string resources file to store all list item labels. So create an XML file under values folder and name it as list_data.xml and paste the following code.
( Right Click on res/values ⇒ New ⇒ Android XML File)

list_data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="adobe_products">
        <item>Adobe After Effects</item>
        <item>Adobe Bridge</item>
        <item>Adobe Dreamweaver</item>
        <item>Adobe Edge</item>
        <item>Adobe Fireworks</item>
        <item>Adobe Flash</item>
        <item>Adobe Photoshop</item>
        <item>Adobe Premiere</item>
        <item>Adobe Reader</item>
        <item>Adobe Illustrator</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

1. In ListView each list item will be an xml layout, so we can customize each list item. Create an XML file under res/layout folder and name it as list_item.xml and type the following code. This xml layout will be single list item row.
   ( Right Click on res/layout ⇒ New ⇒ Android XML File)
2. Now open your main activity java file (AndroidListViewActivity.java) and type the following code. In the following code i am importing all xml resources data and storing them in an Array. On the next step i am binding array to ListAdapter.

AndroidListViewActivity.java

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

    }
}
```

1. Now run your project you can see listview with list of array items. But on clicking single list item you can see no action. So we need to start new activity on selecting single list item.

Launching new Activity on selecting single list item
In my previous article i had explained how to switch between screens. Here i am going to show single list item details in new screen.

1. Now create new activity class under src folder. Right Click on src/package folder ⇒ New ⇒ Class and name it as SingleListItem. (SingleListItem.java)
2. Open your AndroidListViewActivity.java and modify the code to following. In the following code i am getting the selected list item string(product name) and sending it to new Activity.

AndroidListViewActivity.java

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              // selected item 
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });
    }
}
```

Now in new activity we need to display the received from listview activity.

1. Create a new xml file under res/layout and name it as single_list_item_view.xml and type the following code. This XML file will be layout for SingleListItem.java

single_list_item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/product_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

1. Now open your second activity file i.e SingleListItem.java and paste the following code.

SingleListItem.java

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtProduct.setText(product);

    }
}
```

1. The final step is to add an entry of new activity name in AndroidManifest.xml file. Open you AndroidManifest.xml file and modify the code as below

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.androidhive.androidlistview"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroidListViewActivity"
                  android:label="Android List View">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SingleListItem"
                    android:label="Single Item Selected"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

1. Finally run your project by right clicking on your project folder ⇒ Run As ⇒ 1 Android Application.